# Overloading addition operator (adding a string to an object using a function)

Tags: c++, arrays, string, pointers

I'm creating a dynamic array class and I'm new to c++. I'm having trouble overloading the addition operator to add a string to an object. When I do try to add a string, nothing shows up on the compile screen. I also added my copy constructor, destructor, overloaded assignment operator, and overloaded ostream operator just in case any of those were the issue. Thank you so much for the help!!

```
DynamicStringArray::~DynamicStringArray()
{
    delete[] dynamic_Array;
    dynamic_Array = NULL;
}

DynamicStringArray::DynamicStringArray(const DynamicStringArray& first)
{
    size = first.returns_Size();

    dynamic_Array = new string[size];
    for (int n = 0; n < size; n++)
    {
        dynamic_Array[n] = first.get_Entry(n);
    }
}

void DynamicStringArray::operator =(const DynamicStringArray& first)
{
    this->size = first.returns_Size();

    this->dynamic_Array = new string[size];
    for (int i = 0; i < this->size; i++)
    {
        this->dynamic_Array[i] = first.get_Entry(i);
    }
}

ostream& operator <<(ostream& out, const DynamicStringArray& first) //nonmember requires 2 arguments
{
    for (int i = 0; i < first.size; i++)
    {
        out << first.dynamic_Array[i] << endl;
    }
    return out;
}

void DynamicStringArray::add_Entry(string a)
{
    string* Temp_Array = dynamic_Array; //old array
    dynamic_Array = new string[size + 1]; //new array
    
    for (int i= 0; i < size; i++) //copy old string values to temp array
    {
        dynamic_Array[i] = Temp_Array[i];
    }

    dynamic_Array[size] = a; //puts string a into last position of new array

    delete[]Temp_Array; //free memory space

    size++;
}

DynamicStringArray DynamicStringArray::operator +(const string& a)
{
    DynamicStringArray added;
    added.add_Entry(a);
    return added;
}
 

int main()
{
    DynamicStringArray fav_Foods;
    fav_Foods.add_Entry("pasta");
    fav_Foods.add_Entry("sushi");
    fav_Foods + "Burgers";
    cout << fav_Foods << endl;
}
```

Comment: `When I do try to add a string, nothing shows up on the compile screen.` What would you expect to show up on the compile screen?

Comment: So what shows up is the list: pasta, and sushi. But I want the list to be updated to show pasta, sushi, and burger.

Comment: What do you mean "nothing shows up on the compile screen"?    The `operator+()` does not have diagnosable errors, since it is syntactically correct.  Your problem will be in what it does (or doesn't do) since, as you've implemented it, `z = x + y` (where `x` is a `DynamicStringArray` and `y` is a string) will give a result unrelated to `x` - which I suspect is not what you intend.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> DynamicStringArray DynamicStringArray::operator +(const string& a)
> {
>     DynamicStringArray added;
>     added.add_Entry(a);
>     return added;
> }
> ```

Why do you think you need to create a new `DynamicStringArray added`?
Simply call `add_Entry(a)` on the current instance. Also, `operator+()` should return a reference to the instance it is called upon:

```
 DynamicStringArray& DynamicStringArray::operator+(string const &a)
 {
     add_Entry(a);
     return *this;
 }
```

Comment: You've implemented `operator+()` so it works more like what would be normally expected of an `operator+=()`.     It will also mean that `z = x + y` will always change `x` - even if `x` and `z` are unrelated - which is not really desirable behaviour in an addition operator.

Comment: @Peter You are right, should be better called `operator+=()`. But i was under the impression that this is, what the OP wants because of his line `fav_Foods + "Burgers";`